# observable vs render methods jsviews

Tags: javascript, templates, optimization, jsrender, jsviews

Exist: 2500 array object-items.
Render method took 1347.783ms

I`ve tried to optimize timing using $.observable(array).refresh() method and it takes: 3382.213ms

What`s the best way to update view? I thought refresh() method affects only changable items which is not much.

Template:

```html
<script id="betTMPL" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div class="bet_group">
    <div class="bet-title {{if hideGroup}}min{{/if}}" id="group_{{:groupID}}" data-gid="{{:groupID}}" data-gameid="{{:gameID}}">
        <div class="groupName">{^{:groupName}}
            <span id="kolG_{{:groupID}}" {{if !hideGroup}}style="display: none;"{{/if}}> ({{:betsLen}})</span>
            {^{if allowMyMarkets}}
                {^{if actionMyMarket}}
                    <span class="addToMarket" title="<?=__('Add')?>"></span>
                {{else}}
                    <span class="addToMarket active" title="<?=__('Del')?>"></span>
                {{/if}}
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bets" {{if hideGroup}}style="display: none"{{/if}}>
        {^{for bets ~cols=cols ~mainGame=mainGame ~idd=idd ~gameID=gameID ~groupID=groupID}}

            {{if !(#getIndex() % (~cols))}}
                {{if #getIndex() != 0}}
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
                <div>
            {{/if}}

            {^{if #data}}
                <div id="z_{{:T}}">
                    <span class="bet_type {{:spanBetClass}}">{^{:betName}}
                        <span class="koeff {{:classLight}}"
                                {{if ~mainGame}}mainGame="{{:~mainGame}}"{{/if}}
                                {{if DopName}}dopName="{{:DopName}}"{{/if}}
                                bl="{{:B}}"
                                u="{{:~idd}}"
                                idgamecfg="{{:~gameID}}"
                                v="{{:sobID}}"
                                g="{{:~groupID}}"
                                d="{{:P}}"
                                dn="upcoming_events"
                                pl="{{:Pl.Id}}"
                                data-type="{{:T}}"
                                data-coef="{{:C}}"
                                id="b_{{:newID}}"><i>{^{:CV}}</i></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            {{else}}
                <div>&nbsp</div>
            {{/if}}

            {{if #getIndex() == #get("array").data.length - 1}}
                </div>
            {{/if}}
        {{/for}}
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `{^{for bets ...}}...{{/for}}` and you call `$.observable(bets).refresh(newBets)` then you are replacing the whole `bets` array with a new `newBets` array, so the whole content of that `{{for}}` block will be completely re-rendered and re-linked - which will be as slow as the original rendering.

If the change to the array is incremental, and can be expressed in terms of one or more [insert](http://www.jsviews.com/#insert) or [remove](http://www.jsviews.com/#remove) operations, then that will allow JsViews to know that only the added/removed/moved items should be re-rendered, and it will be much faster. [Move](http://www.jsviews.com/#move) operations have been optimized in a recent update.

See http://www.jsviews.com/#arrchange

For more complex changes to arrays, you can use [compiled View Models](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvviewmodelsapi), and use the [merge()](http://www.jsviews.com/#viewmodelsapi@merge) feature. Since a recent update (78) the merge() operation has been optimized, and is usually much faster (including for arrays) provided you define identity, by a primary key field or similar. See http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvviewmodelsapi@mergeadvsample.

Comment: Appreciate your answer.
I`ve made a fiddle that fully demostrate my problem.
Could you please advice the way to solve.
Merging the same data -
Link: 1779.328ms
Merge: 6253.951ms

https://jsfiddle.net/bc335zyx/2/

Comment: Thanks for providing the jsfiddle. I am investigating. Unfortunately both move and the compiled View Model approach are not in fact optimized for arrays (I misspoke) - so the {^{for}} block will re-render for the whole array. It may be possible to change that in a JsViews update - but I can't promise. Working on it... I updated my reply above...

Comment: Good news - I was able to do the optimization work, and it is in the latest version: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/commit/91d5e6309d7b4d93c9d51117201cd42142429601. The merge in the jsfiddle above now takes 271ms. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you so much.
Also one more question.
Is it possible to 
`this.model = $.extend({}, {
                        balance: null,
                        tabs: null,
                        lastBets: null
                    });

                    $.templates("#lobby").link(this.diceMainContainer, this.model);`

after this make
`$.observable(_this.model).setProperty("lastBets", { activeLastBetsType: _this.activeLastBetsType, bets: [] });
                $.observable(_this.model.lastBets.bets).refresh(res.Value.Bets.slice());`

It doesnt work.

Comment: That should be possible. You must have a bug in your code. Create a small jsfiddle if you can't get it to work. Just the minimal content to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please note that compare the same objects are from e.g. AJAX response === is not equal
jsviews.js #3229 #3233
JSON.stringify(newItem) === JSON.stringify(data[i]) - work well

Comment: Oh sorry for that.
Please note that compare the same objects are from e.g. AJAX response === is not equal jsviews.js #3229 #3233 JSON.stringify(newItem) === JSON.stringify(data[i]) - work well

Comment: Oh sorry for that.
Please note that compare the same objects are from e.g. AJAX response === is not equal jsviews.js #3229 #3233 
JSON.stringify(newItem) === JSON.stringify(data[i]) - work well
One last question above. Object properties is not equal because of modified after .link() method. So after calling .refresh() method to compare new but the same array objects causes re-render the whole array.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the specifics of your implementation or scenario, and can't help you with details of that. If you find a bug in JsViews you can create an issue, with a jsfiddle  to show it. (Really minimal - without your application specific data etc which just takes time to decipher, and is not relevant :) )

Comment: Found another misunderstanding..Creating a fiddle based on your doc sample. 
https://jsfiddle.net/bc335zyx/5/
Values will not update with merge() if they were passed like ~val=val() in loop. Please advice a solution because of stop developing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bc335zyx/6/ shows a couple of alternatives. See http://www.jsviews.com/#linked-tag-syntax@linkedproperties

Comment: Thank you for your support. Is it any alternative way to do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bc335zyx/7/

Comment: You have a <tr> containing a <tr> so obviously your fiddle is not working. :(  https://jsfiddle.net/bc335zyx/9/. I can help with bugs, but otherwise I don't have time available - so, to be frank, I'd appreciate if you don't ask for help before spending time first yourself !.

Comment: Actually my question was not clearly. https://jsfiddle.net/bc335zyx/10/. Here is the new sample. Is it possible to make open-close tags in loop to change number of columns which is dynamic. It`s important feature for me. I`ve read http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvtags Rules for a well-formed template. So there is now way except multiple {^{for}} for dynamic columns? Sorry, didnt found with google :(

Comment: It`s really last question..
jsfiddle.net/bc335zyx/10
Link() - good.
Update or revert - jsviews.js:4050 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined

Comment: I haven't been able to look at the last two jsfiddles yet. I hope to get to it before long...

Comment: You have to have a well-formed template to work with observable changes in JsViews. You should do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/bc335zyx/11/
BTW in the next update of JsViews you will not need to write `^~name=name()`. `~name=name()` will work and support updates!